# Как можно увеличить стандартный UIPickerView на Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как можно увеличить стандартный UIPickerView на Swift.
В стандартной UIPickerView есть только 5 видимых строк.
Нужен PickerView с размером во весь экран.

Может кто-нибудь помочь с этой проблемой?

Нужен PickerView как на этой картинке

[image: Needed PickerView]

Comment: Решение найдено https://github.com/roofeel/DDMultiPickerView
Одна проблема код на Objective-C придется либо использовать готовое решение через bridging header, либо переписать класс на Swift

Comment: отлично! Если не трудно, напишите сами себе ответ с решением — пускай оно пригодится тем, кто в будущем будет решать эту же задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено github.com/roofeel/DDMultiPickerView Одна проблема код на Objective-C придется, либо использовать готовое решение через bridging header, либо переписать класс на Swift